# XSL Transformation to split a single node into two nodes in the same level

Tags: xslt

I have a source XML

```
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Make>Fiat</Make>
    <Colors>
      <Color>RED</Color>
      <Color>BLUE</Color>
    </Colors>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>Volvo</Make>
    <Colors>
      <Color>RED</Color>
      <Color>WHITE</Color>
    </Colors>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Make>Renault</Make>
    <Colors>
      <Color>BLUE</Color>
      <Color>BLACK</Color>
    </Colors>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

which I want to transform into something like

```
<Cars>
  <Detail>
    <Name>MakeName</Name>
    <Entry>Fiat</Entry>
    <Entry>Volvo</Entry>
    <Entry>Renault</Entry>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Name>AvailableColors</Name>
    <Entry>RED</Entry>
    <Entry>BLUE</Entry>
    <Entry>WHITE</Entry>
    <Entry>BLACK</Entry>
  </Detail>
<Cars>
```

I am new to XSL, and created one to do half of processing, but I am stuck with the getting of colors as separate elements in target

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Cars>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </Cars>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cars">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Car" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Car">
  <Detail>
    <Name>MakeName</Name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Make" />
  </Detail>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Make">
  <Entry><xsl:value-of select"text()"/></Entry>
</xsl:template>
```

I am not able to create XSL for `<Name>AvailableColors</Name>`, I am quite new to XSL and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Side note: Is your business logic still valid after applying the transformation? I'd expect a WHITE Renault being available from your result but there is none in your source.

Comment: We needed an xml that can give the car makes and colors as separate unique elements. The business logic was to split the source xml element 'Car' into two result xml elements 'Make' and 'Color'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that shows how to eliminate duplicate colors using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Car/Colors/Color" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="Cars">
  <xsl:copy>
    <Detail>
      <Name>MakeName</Name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Car/Make"/>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Name>AvailableColors</Name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Car/Colors/Color[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]"/>
    </Detail>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Car/Make | Colors/Color">
  <Entry>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Entry>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**See a generic "shredding" solution given in this answer**:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597577/36305

Comment: hello there :) the OP seems to be a rookie in XSLT, I guess he would find it difficult to refer other examples and design his own code.

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind': I also see now that the OP didn't use the term "split" in the sence of shredding. This is just regular grouping. I will delete my answer.